# Setting edge width in Rgraphviz

Tags: r, graph, graphviz

Apparently, it is possible, although not well documented, to set the edge width in Rgraphviz. Here is one way to do it:

```
library(graph)
library(Rgraphviz)
nodes <- c( LETTERS[1:3] )
edgesL <- list( A=c("B", "C"), B=c("A", "C"), C=c("B", "A" ) )
graph <- new( "graphNEL", nodes= nodes, edgemode="undirected", edgeL=edgesL )
rag <- agopen( graph, "" )
rag@AgEdge[[1]]@lwd <- 5
plot(rag)
```

The slot "lwd" is explicitly defined in the AgEdge man page. Result:

[image]

So far, so good. However, I cannot access the AgEdge object with edge ID (i.e., "A~C"), only with a numeric index. How do I use the above approach to tell graphviz to change the lwd for the edge between A and C?

The proper way to add values of the attributes would be through the edgeAttrs option to agopen(), however. Let's try with a documented attribute:

```
eAttrs <- list( color=c( "A~C"="red" ) )
rag <- agopen( graph, "", edgeAttrs=eAttrs )
plot(rag)
```

OK, the result is correct:

[image]

OK, how about lwd, then; but -- bummer:

```
> eAttrs <- list( lwd=c( "A~C"=5 ) )
> rag <- agopen( graph, "", edgeAttrs=eAttrs )
Error in buildEdgeList(graph, recipEdges, edgeAttrs, subGList, attrs$edge) : 
  no slot of name "name" for this object of class "pEdge"
```

Weirdly enough, when you look up the agopen function, you find the following snippet of code:

```
if (!is.null(edgeAttrs$lwd)) {
    for (i in seq(along = edgeAttrs$lwd)) {
        attr(attr(g, "AgEdge")[[i]], "lwd") <- edgeAttrs$lwd[i]
    }
}
```

This looks like in theory, edgeAttrs should be able to handle lwd. The documentation is not helpful, unfortunately: if you look up the manual page for "agopen", it tells you

```
 For a description of ‘attrs’, ‘nodeAttrs’ and ‘edgeAttrs’, see the
 ‘Ragraph’ man page.
```

However, "edgeAttrs" are not mentioned in the Ragraph man page at all. I am confused and angry. And desperate. Desperate people study the source code. Apparently, `agopen()` throws an error, because `getDefaultAttrs()` doesn't know about the lwd slot. We can amend it, though:

```
eAttrs <- list( lwd=list( "A~C"=5, "A~B"=1 ) )
rag <- agopen( graph, "", edgeAttrs=eAttrs, attrs= list(edge=list(lwd=2)) )
plot(rag)
```

This at least doesn't produce an error message, but produces an incorrect graph:

[image]

This is because this weird code snippet above uses `seq(along= .. )` to fill out the lwd information, completely ignoring the fact that this is a named list and we want to enter the information by edge names, not their order.

So, my question. Is there a simple, documented way of displaying a graph with varying edge widths in R / Rgraphviz? (I need Rgraphviz because I want to draw the nodes with a custom function, other packages do not provide this functionality, I think).

Or do I need to code my own crutches? Oh, I can do it, here is a function that sets an attribute for an edge between ID1 and ID2 (which can be vectors of the same length, providing value is also a vector of the same length):

```
setEdgeAttr <- function( graph, attribute, value, ID1, ID2 ) {

  idfunc <- function(x) paste0( sort(x), collapse="~" )
  all.ids <- sapply( AgEdge(graph), 
    function(e) idfunc( c( attr(e, "head"), attr( e, "tail" ))))

  sel.ids <- apply(cbind( ID1, ID2 ), 1, idfunc )

  if(!all(sel.ids %in% all.ids)) stop( "only existing edges, please" )
  sel <- match( sel.ids, all.ids )

  for(i in 1:length(sel)) {
    attr( attr( graph, "AgEdge" )[[ sel[i] ]], attribute ) <- value[i]
  }

  return(graph)
}
```

Does it work? Oh, yes:

```
rag <- agopen( graph, "" )
rag <- setEdgeAttr( rag, "lwd", c(5, 20), c("B", "B"), c( "A", "C" ) )
plot(rag)
```

[image]

I just can't believe there is no easier way.

Comment: When I find and can fix shortcomings in packages I like or rely on, I typically contact the package maintainer with a suggested fix/enhancement. It looks to me like you're skilled enough to provide that kind of help and, in my experience, maintainers are invariably happy for any incremental improvements that you'll be willing to contribute. i.e. don't get angry, get helpful ;)!

Comment: Well, first I want to find out whether there is really a shortcoming in such an old package.

Comment: Very understandable. Also, hope I didn't come off as condescending or accusing. It's just that what you've discovered here strikes me as *just* the kind of detail that can go unnoticed for a long time, even in more venerable packages. Just last week, I submitted several patches to the *very* well exercised **sp** package, giving users the option of passing vectors of colors with which to draw multiple polygons and lines in maps with multiple layers.